# Is there a recommended repository layout for script libraries?

Tags: svn, version-control

*Disclaimer*—I'm quite familiar with the best practices around repository layout for larger software projects, however they seems like a fair bit of overkill for maintaining a collection of (mostly) single-file scripts.

My script library consists of various languages (Perl, batch, Powershell, etc.), and are mostly command-line utilities. I am looking to wrap some source control around them to cover the following main use cases:

- Isolating development branches (adding features, commandline options, etc).

  - Most commonly, I slam something together for a once-off ad-hoc task, and later on I modify & improve it for more general use.
- Having something to go back to in the case of introducing a bug that I might not notice for weeks or months.

## Keep It Simple, Stupid

I thought initially to simply drop my scripts folder as-is into the repository.

The upside is it's very simple and allows for painless `svn export` "deployments". The downside is a lack of separation between completely unrelated script files (the only thing they share in common is they exist in a folder that is prepended to my %PATH% variable): any work would involve branching the entire folder structure. This is by no means a deal-breaker; it's just not ideal, IMO.

## Isolation bears hope?

A folder-per-script approach.

The upside is it gives me a point from which I can branch on individual scripts. The downsides are that: a) it very suddenly approaches a standard repository structure (trunk, tags, branches), with all the associated overheads; b) .

If there is any middle ground between the two, I can't seem to find it.

Source control is very much in the category of things I'd prefer to get right from the beginning, before I commit myself to going down one road or the other.

---

*FYI, I posted this question on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and it was downvoted into oblivion with no explanation. To anyone intending to do the same here, I would appreciate the entry-level courtesy of an explanation.*

*I spent time trying to find any answer to this question before I posted it, I clearly outlined what I had already considered and the pros and cons of each, what I was trying to achieve (and what I wasn't), why my case was (IMO) sufficiently different from the most common case that most SVN literature is aimed at.*

*I didn't just fire this off lazily without trying to do any research, and I did not think it deserved such shabby treatment.*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you keep your SCM separetely from release/distribution system. Like you may have branches, tags and whatever directories layouts in SCM and then make a releases/distribution of your scripts with proper tool. You make take a look at [sparrow](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrow) - tool to develop and distribute scripts. At least it may solve some of mentioned issues by treating scripts as usual packages of software with versions, ownership and documentation.

PS. Disclosure - I am the tool author

Comment: Appreciate the input. I will have a closer look at this when I can.

Comment: Yeah, sure , will be glad to help you, if you choose to use sparrow -)